# Print the longest alphabetical substring using Python and for ties, print the first substring

Tags: python, python-2.7, substring, alphabetical

Assume s is a string of lower case characters.
Write a program that prints the longest substring of s in which the letters occur in alphabetical order.

For example, if s = 'azcbobobegghakl', then your program should print

> Longest substring in alphabetical order is: beggh

In the case of ties, print the first substring. For example, if s = 'abcbcd', then your program should print

> Longest substring in alphabetical order is: abc

Here's the code I found. How do I implement the latter condition in the question given above regarding ties?

```
    *s = raw_input('provide string: ')
    result = []
    final = []
    for letters in s:
        result = result + [letters]        
        if result == sorted(result) and len(result) >= len(final):
            final = result            
        elif result != sorted(result):
            result = [result[len(result)-1]]        
    print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: '+(''.join(final)))*
```

Comment: Your question should include the code that you have tried, and the problem you encountered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd approach the problem the following way:

- Let's define two strings: The `current` string of increasing letters and the currently `longest` string.
- Both strings are initialized with the first letter. (This way we can always read their last letter.)
- Then we iterate over the input string `s` (starting with the second character).
- If the current character `c` fulfills the requirement `c >= current[-1]`, we add it to the current solution.
- We possibly store the `current` string as `longest`.
- If `c` does not fulfill the ordering requirement, we start with a new solution `current = c`.
- Finally, we print the `longest` string.

```py
s = "azcbobobegghakl"
longest = s[0]
current = s[0]
for c in s[1:]:
    if c >= current[-1]:
        current += c
        if len(current) > len(longest):
            longest = current
    else:
        current = c
print "Longest substring in alphabetical order is:", longest
```

---

**How to fix your code wrt. the mentioned condition:**

Use `>` instead of `>=` in the comparison `len(result) >= len(final)`, i.e. only update the `final` solution if it is *longer*, but not if it has the same length.

---

**Considering Dylans comment**

You're right. I updated both code and description to correctly handle the case when `s` ends with the longest alphabetical substring. (Moving `else:` two lines down was sufficient.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm a python beginner and I didn't know heads or tails about how to fix this problem.

Comment: you need to add one line above your print statement(out of that for loop), which is your if len(current)> len(longest): longest = current.  Since if you don't, the update of longest = current within the forloop may not happen.  Try the test case 'abcdef' you will know what I mean.